# VBA: SUMIFS loop for an Array criteria (not a formula)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, sumifs

I'm struggling with this one:

I have a sheet with a large datasheet of billing information related to shipping tracking numbers.
The same tracking could appear multiple times in the "Lead Shipment Number" column but entries in the "Charge Description" column will contain multiple different strings (eg. "Ground Residential", "Ground Commercial", "Fuel Surcharge", etc.).

On a separate sheet, I have a column with only the UNIQUE tracking numbers.
I need to SUM values of a third column ("Net Amount") in the main dataset if the tracking number and any one of variety of strings exist in the "Charge Description" column in the same row as the tracking number. I need this to loop through and do this for all the UNIQUE tracking numbers. I'm not permitted to use formulas for this project.

[image: DataSetExample_EntriesBeginOnRow3]

Here's a code I've been working on - right now, it keeps entering the same two values on repeat:

```
Sub SumIfsMultipleCriteria()
    Dim sumRange As Range
    Dim criteriaRange1 As Range
    Dim criteriaRange2 As Range
    Dim Result As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Long
    Dim TrackingNumber As String
    Dim criteria As Variant

    k = 1

    Set sumRange = Sheets("UPS_All Raw Data Combined").Range("BA3:BA100")
    Set criteriaRange1 = Sheets("UPS_All Raw Data Combined").Range("N3:N100")
    Set criteriaRange2 = Sheets("UPS_All Raw Data Combined").Range("AT3:AT100")
   
    TrackingNumber = "*" & Sheets("VBA").Range("I" & k + 1) & "*"

    criteria = Array("Ground Residential", "Ground Commercial")

    For j = 3 To 50
        For i = 0 To UBound(criteria)

            Result = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Result, _
                WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(sumRange, criteriaRange1, TrackingNumber, criteriaRange2, criteria(i)))
        Sheets("VBA").Range("C" & k + 1) = Result
        Result = 0
        k = k + 1
        Next i
    
    Next j

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you are trying to keep a running `Result` why are you returning it to `0` inside each loop? And the J loop is not doing anything to change the variables inside the sumifs.  TrackingNumber will always be the same.  So yeah you are always going to get the same two numbers.  TrackinNumber being assigned a value should probably be inside the loop.

Comment: I found that moving the TrackingNumber identifier to the loop does seem to work better. However now I find that if the found tracking number has two value that I want to add together for the Result (eg. Ground Residential = 7.92 and Ground Commercial = 0) I get zero instead of 7.92.

Comment: Move the `Result = 0` after the `Next i`

Comment: I've tried changing the order of Result = 0 & k = k + 1 moving them around before Next i and after it in various attempts but I keep getting the same result (calculating zero when it should give me 7.92).